# IBMMQDotnetClient nuget package behavior in .NET Core/Standard projects

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, ibm-mq

There are two projects that use `IBMMQDotnetClient` 9.2.1 nuget package, in the solution that I work with.

The first project is a console app, and it is .NET Core 2.1. It compiles without issues, but in the VS UI, the namespace `IBM.WMQ` and all classes from it are underlined and as long as the class file that uses them is open, there are similar errors in the list:

> CS0246    The type or namespace name 'IBM' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The second project is a MSTest project. It does not compile, due to the same error as the false-positive error above.

I tried to clear nuget package cache numerous times, restarted the machine, restarted VS, closed and reopened the solution without closing VS, but none of this fixed the issue. I am on the latest VS 2017 as of today.

This very same `IBMMQDotnetClient` works perfectly fine in a full framework 4.7.1 solution under VS 2015 with these same two projects.

Any ideas what more VS 2017 needs?

Comment: That is the latest continuous delivery release, have you tried with the latest long term support release (9.2.0.1)?

Comment: I don't have VS2017, so I tried with VS2019. No errors are shown in 2019.

Comment: @JoshMc This is very interesting! Where did you find this info? Yes, downgrading fixed the intelisense underlines in the 1st project.

Comment: This was just a troubleshooting guess.  System requirements/Software support for both 9.2.1 and 9.2.0.1 indicate support for VS2017.  If you have a IBM support contract you should open a case to find out why it did not work.